# How to add row automatically in between filled row like google form in google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

So, right now I'm working on adding data to my spreadsheet using google form. I would like to add my second google form response below my first google form response automatically by adding row automatically (im doing this process in another sheet using importrange), even in my first google response has some data on it. The content of these two google form remain the same so i would like to see it in 1 sheet.

The reason why i want to do this is to minimize to create another spreadsheet to collect all the data. When im doing this i always get an error message "#REF!" because i know google form using array to add response.

[What i want is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8Dfw.png)

Can you guys please help me with it?
Here is my [folder](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1zqDad2OTDj02uww7DYy-PkH0UG7j05uZ?usp=sharing).

Thankyou

Comment: What exactly is it that you want to achieve? If the content of these forms remains the same, why isn't this an option `={'Question 1'!A1:B11 ; 'Question 2'!A1:B8}`?

Comment: Its exactly just like what you wrote right here, Thankyou @ale13 !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the below formula which essentially merges the two different ranges from the two different sheets:

```
={'Question 1'!A1:B11 ; 'Question 2'!A1:B8}
```